# How can we compare the time format such that [ 00:00:10 and 00:00:22 ]?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have the execution times of program which are like so 00:00:10, 00:30:23

The question is how can I compare them to each other?

```
val1="00:00:10"
val2="00:30:23"

if [ "$val1" -gt "$val2" ]; then
    echo "bigger"
else
    echo "smaller"
fi
```

this give an error that they are not INTEGERS.

So, when I changed the code without -gt to > it does not work too..

Could you let me know how can we compare the time formats such that I explained above ?

Thank a lot..

Comment: If you don't find a simpler solution, the arithmetic way would always work : split over colon, multiply hours by 3600 and minutes by 60 and add hours/minutes/seconds to eachother

Comment: hi @Aaron its great idea,I will try to do such that until find an easy way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead use `[[ "$val1" > "$val2" ]]` to compare dates:

```
─$ if [[ 00:00:10 > 00:30:23 ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
no
─$ if [[ 00:00:10 < 00:30:23 ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes
```